# Impact of border property on top margin

Tags: html, css, margin

Refer to the following code:

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  /* border: solid 1px black; */
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I remove `border: solid 1px black` from .header I get some space above div element. But when I add the border property I get the perfect results (that is space removed). What should be impact of border property on this space?

Comment: you need to bit understand how `box model` works. check  this link. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: ul {margin: 0;} - this is your problem!

Comment: How margin of ul is impacting position of div element and how border property is impacting it ?

Answer (score 5):

This is due to margin collapsing ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)).

In your example the header element contains an unordered list which, by default, has a top and bottom margin. Because of border collapsing, its margin is transferred to the header which in turn is transferred to the body. As a result, the body is pushed down while the header and list aligns with the top of body.

[image: top: margin of ul, bottom: margin of body]

Adding a border is one method to prevent margin collapsing (see W3 specs). If you want to avoid adding a border, use the other methods  such as assign `overflow: hidden` to the header.

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  /*border: solid 1px black;  */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Borders should not affect margins (edit: except here because of margin collapsing, see @salman-a's answer. My bad. But you should still use a CSS reset).

I think you need some sort of [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/)

One I find usefull for quick testing is the simplest of all (but not recommended to use in other cases, beacause it is way to simple):

```
*{padding:0;margin:0}
```

This will clear all browser padding/margin.

I think the problem here is you did not reset your header and ul margins, and the browser adds them (browser do that in order to display stuff nicely, even if there is no CSS).

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? They should just be added to each other. The link posted above says it all: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp That is if you do not use box-sizing property of course.

Comment: Oh you're right, didn't know borders prevented margin collapsing. I just avoid it whenever I can and use the overflow:hidden trick if needed. That makes you answer more relevant that mine (but I will edit it). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your ul tag is not clear

```css
body{
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;  
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgray; 
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 

  background-color: yellow; 
  /*border: solid 1px black;*/  
}
ul{float: left;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>   
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is float:left related to this issue ? And actually you forgot to clear it